# Avoiding n+1 query bug in rails has many association

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

There are many answers with this particular topic but I am not finding any one perfectly suited for me. I have a recipe app where in I need all the users who gave particular ratings to that recipe(example: list of user who gave rating 5 to particular recipe) without having an n+1 query bug. I know it can be solved using includes option but in belongs to reference I don't know how to use it. I am using rails 3.2.15.

below is the modal level description of my app

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'creator_id'
  has_many :photos, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :ingredients, :through => :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :ratings, :dependent => :destroy
end


class  Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'rater_id'
  belongs_to :recipe
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'creator_id'
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :recipes, :through => :recipe_ingredients 
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipes , foreign_key: "creator_id", class_name: "Recipe", :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :ingredients, foreign_key: "creator_id", class_name: "Ingredient", :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :ratings, foreign_key: "rater_id", class_name: "Rating", :dependent => :destroy
end
```

**My query to retrieve users is**

```
@rec = Recipe.find(params[:id])
ratings = @rec.ratings.where(:ratings => params[:ratings])

users = ratings.map {|rate| rate.user}
```

this introduces an n+1 query bug is there any proper way in use rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified query:

```
users = ratings.includes(:user).select('users.name')
```

I have added `select('users.name')` considering you have name column in users. You can use any column you want for the view.

Comment: thanks! buddy it helped a lot. I was trying with includes(:users), association really matters with names you put

Answer (score 1):

An answer by *@VedprakashSingh* has a major downside of returning instances of `Rating` populated with data from `User`. So, suddenly, you're left without all the `User`'s methods. Type safety is thrown out the window.

What you can do instead is a `joins`/`merge` combo to fetch instances of one model with conditions on the other one. Like so:

```
User.joins(:ratings).merge(
  # Here you can place a relation of ratings
  @rec.ratings.where(:ratings => params[:ratings])
  # Yes, it's your line, copy-pasted from your question
) # ...and back here we get users joined with these
```

So you explicitly start the query with the fact that you want `User`s. Then you join the tables, getting a **huge** set of every rating joined with its `user` (all still in the database!). Contents of `merge` then filter down ratings in that set to the ones you want.

**Beware**, as the line I've copied from the question may be vulnerable to faking parameters, it's not filtered. You have `ratings` table, so if `params[:ratings]` turns out to be a hash (that **can** be done, it's literally user's input) it will be treated as a hash of conditions allowing the user to send any hash-based conditions.

```
yoursite.com/whatever?ratings[id]=12
```

That query string will result in `params[:ratings]` being:

```
{"id" => "12"} # Damn right, a Ruby hash
```

[Strong parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) exist for a reason.